# svn merge include start revision

Tags: svn, unix, command-line, merge

To merge a range of revisions, we use svn merge -r  from to where start and end are revision IDs. This will merge all revisions starting at start+1 up to and INCLUDING end.

It will NOT include the first revision (ex: -r3:45 will merge 4 through 45).

How to include -r3 too when i try to do the merge -r3:45. I know by giving -r2:45 will fix it but i have a script which is grabbing these revisions based on ticket numbers and is missing out on start revision number and causing compile issues.

Is there any arg to pass on `svn merge` to include start rev too ?

Comment: Uhm, why do you not fix your script, so it "fixes" the arguments for you...?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the non-numeric arguments:

- '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date (yyyy-mm-dd)
- 'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
- 'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
- 'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED

**References**

- [SVN Merge MAN page](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/svn-merge.txt)